# Simple Synchronous Rectification of Unidirectional Motor?

Tags: mosfet, motor, motor-controller, mosfet-driver, flyback

I'm trying to drive a high current, low voltage motor (24V 100A cont.). It previously used a very large and overpowered H-Bridge (16 FETs). The system only can rotate 1 direction, and is required to coast stop (no active braking).

So instead of a full H bridge, I figured it would be much more compact to drive it with a single low side FET (2 in parallel). Unfortunately the losses in the flyback diode would be quite large, then it occurred to me, I should be able to use a typical half bridge driver with dead time etc. built in, and just put the high side FET across the motor.

The body diode would conduct in the required times when the FET is not activated, and once activated it would have orders of magnitude less losses. One risk is the bootstrap system would eventually under volt when left on for extended time, but it would not matter as the motor would be stopped, and the body diode is still there for over voltage prevention in case of manual motion.

It seems to easy, but I have yet to find an issue with this concept. Am I missing something obvious? If not, hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

[image]

Comment: Low side PWM, is needed to create high side boost voltage when needed.  Low capacitance high side of preferred

Comment: @Tony Since the low side is what is driving the motor, the boost should always be charged up when the motor is stopped or running at partial power. Unless I'm not understanding your comment. What do you mean by low capacitance high side.

Comment: you rely on the body diode on high side switch when starting the PWM on low side, this then drives the charge pump required for the high side driver.